# What's the Widget name for in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

it's been a while since I started to flutter and since then I'm a beginner at it. Today I've come across some really cool and nice widgets which I can't seem to find anywhere on the internet since I don't even know their names. So, as an example, I'm showing the picture of it. I just need to know the name of this widget.

[image]

You can clearly see that there's some sort of progress indicator but with a totally different look and feel and it's connected through smaller circles as well.

THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Flutter

This UI Component is referred as **Stepper**, in this [link](https://fluttergems.dev/stepper/) you would find a lot of Flutter packages that provide a ready made widget for it.

Comment: Seems like I got the fish. 

THANKS!!!

Comment: Glad to here that, You are always welcome ❤